# Use "this" in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is as follows:

```
function editIncome(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var amount = $(this).data('amount');
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    var user = $(this).data('user');
    $('input[name="income_id"]').val(id);
    $('input[name="income_name"]').val(name);
    $('input[name="income_amount"]').val(amount);
    $("#incomeEdit").modal('show');
}
```

I recently changed it from `$(".editIncome").click(function(){...});` to a `function editIncome(){...}` and now the `$(this)` call is not loading anything in the function.

My question is how do  I get that working again with the function call? How do I use the `this` keyword on a function? I have multiple items with the same `.editIncome` class so I need to choose the one that was clicked.

I am calling the function by doing this: `<a class="list-group-item editIncome" onclick="editIncome();" href="#">...</a>`

Comment: How do you now call the function?

Comment: try `$(".editIncome").click(editIncome)`. Passing as reference will give you `this` context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either pass the function name directly:

```
$(".editIncome").click(editIncome);
```

Or when calling the the function, use call to set the value of `this` inside the function:

```
$(".editIncome").click(function() {
  editIncome.call(this);
});
```

---

Since the update:

```
<a class="list-group-item editIncome" onclick="editIncome.call(this)" href="#">...</a>
```

The value of `this` inside `editIncome` will be the HTML element.

Comment: check updated question. This is not how I am calling.

Answer (score 0):

When you had $(".editIncome") , $(this) meant $(".editIncome"), it was shortcut ,but when u deleted $(".editIncome"), $(this) points to nothing .

Comment: Simply Type: 
$(this) = $(".editIncome")  and it will work you must set pointer to something, otherwise $(this) has no value